# How do I lock h-space?

Tags: formatting

like

```
a = 5                                 [a is 5]

b = 555555555555555555                [b = 55...]
```

like where the brackets are [a is 5]. I wanted it even with the top part always

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! This is something a tabular can do for you. This site is full of examples.

Comment: These are two very basic examples: `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}l}
a = 5 &                                 [a is 5]\\
b = 555555555555555555         &       [b = 55\dots]\\
\end{tabular}
\[
\begin{array}{p{5cm}l}
$a = 5$ &                                 [a\text{ is }5]\\
$b = 555555555555555555$         &       [b = 55\dots]\\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}`. To really answer the question one needs more information about the context (text vs. math mode, are these equations, etc.).

Comment: its math mode so equations

Answer (score 2):

I will be happy to remove this. You said equations, OK, so

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
a &= 5 &   &                              [a\text{ is }5]\\
b &= 555555555555555555         &  &     [b = 55\dots]\\
\end{align*}

\newtagform{square}[][]
\usetagform{square}
\begin{align*}
a &= 5                            \tag{$a$ is 5}\\
b &= 555555555555555555         \tag{$b = 55\dots$}\\
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]